# How to sort an ArrayList<String> based on specific index range

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

My need is to sort the ArrayList of Strings, based on specific index range. For example I have following items in list: `["abc", "xyz", "pqr" , "asd"]`Now I want to sort this list from index 1 till last index.

One way As I think that I can create a sub-list from main list with desired index range, sort it and add the sub-list accordingly. But my question is:

Is there any API already available for that? Or any other faster way to achieve this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should do

```
Collections.sort(yourList.subList(1, yourList.size()));
```

Since the `List.subList` method returns a *view* of the list, modifications done by `Collections.sort` will affect the backing list as well.

Answer (score 0):

`DetailsVOTemp` Model have Time and Add set-get method 
and I have already one list which is a list with the name of list
Get the time and lat long from the list and store in tow `ArrayList` than finally sort it

```
    List< DetailsVOTemp> firstlist = new ArrayList<>();
    List<DetailsVOTemp> secondlisr = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         DetailsVOTemp mDetailsVOTemp = new  DetailsVOTemp();
        mDetailsVOTemp.setTime(list.get(i).getTime());
        mDetailsVOTemp.setAdd(list.get(i).getLatLong());
        mVoTemps.add(mDetailsVOTemp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        DetailsVOTemp mDetailsVOTemp = new  DetailsVOTemp();
        mDetailsVOTemp.setTime(list.get(i).getDropOffTime());
        mDetailsVOTemp.setAdd(list.get(i).getDropLatLong());
        mVoTemps1.add(mDetailsVOTemp);
    }

    mVoTemps.addAll(mVoTemps1);
    Collections.sort(mVoTemps, new Comparator<DetailsVOTemp>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(DetailsVOTemp o1, DetailsVOTemp o2) {
            return o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime());
        }
    });

    StringBuilder mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder mBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mVoTemps.size(); i++) {
        mBuilder1.append(mVoTemps.get(i).getTime() +" :: ");
        mBuilder.append(mVoTemps.get(i).getAdd() +" :: ");
    }

    Log.d("Time : ", mBuilder1.toString());
    Log.d("Address : ", mBuilder.toString());
```